# How can we define the roles in the hyperleedger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

For example, If my network running on multiple machines and there are 2 organizations and one orderer int the network. How can I define the roles of both organizations and their peers. One organizations have multiple peers. How the ledger will behave on all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this you can mention all policies except chaincode policy in configtx.yml
Sample:

```
- &maersksea
    Name: maersksea
    ID: maersksea
    MSPDir: ./peerOrganizations/maersksea/msp
    AdminPrincipal: Role.ADMIN
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer-maersksea-peer
          Port: 7051
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('maersksea.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('maersksea.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('maersksea.admin')"
```